# Как сжать/растянуть текст в css

Tags: html, css

Имеется некий текст в `<h3>` и я хочу сжимать или растягивать его по ширине на 50%. Как это можно сделать?

```
<h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
```

Оригинальный текст
[image: оригинал]

Растянутый текст на 50%
[image: растянутый]

Сжатый текст на 50%
[image: сжатый]

Comment: transform:scaleX/Y

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(8, 6);
}
```

```html
<h1>Текст<h1>
```

Comment: Ну, почти. Вместо scale(8, 6) нужно либо scaleX(1.5), либо scaleX(0.5).

Comment: @ИльяКузьмич ну да, это просто пример, scale(8, 6) это по X и Y